# accessing prolog list term

Tags: prolog, jpl

I've been using jpl for calling prolog from java. I'm using the following code in java to get the value of X from prolog.

```
String t4 = "myNumber(X)";
Query q4 = new Query(t4);
System.out.println( "first solution of " + t4 + ": X = " + q4.oneSolution().get("X"));
```

And my solution is--

```
first solution of myNumber(X): X = '.'(2, [])--which is true.
```

What i wanted to do now is to obtain the value 2 from the solution and double the number.
Can anyone help me how to handle that?

Comment: You should consider another title for the question. At least I don't see any connection to JPanel and JMenuBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oneSolution() returns a hashtable of variablename-to-term bindings ([they say](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/java_api/javadoc/jpl/Query.html)). Then you have to inspect to the term (untested):

```
Term listTerm = q4.oneSolution().get("X");
Term firstListItem = listTerm.arg(1);
double value = firstListItem.doubleValue(); // alternatively, use intValue() or so
```

Also check [Term](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/java_api/javadoc/jpl/Term.html)'s documentation.

**Edit:** fixed mistakes

Comment: I meant listTerm.arg(1), of course. Remember you should accept answers of your questions. You haven't accepted any of your old questions. You won't get many answers unless you do that.

Comment: i'm new to this site..so did not know that i should accept answers..sorry for that

Comment: In the same way if the solution is **myNumber(X): X = '.'(2, '.'(3, []))** how should i pass the arguments to obtain all the values 2,3, etc...

Comment: `void toList(Term t, List xs) { if (t.arity() == 2) { xs.add(t.arg(1).doubleValue()); toList(t.arg(2), xs); } }` or you might wanna use Term.toTermArray(), I suspect

Comment: i've tried using Term.toTermArray() but was not successful. My part of code is `public Term[] toTermArray(Object k1) {
  try {
  int len = this.listLength(k1);
  Term[] ts = new Term[len];
  Term t = this;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   ts[i] = t.arg(1);
  t = t.arg(2);
  }
    return ts;
   } catch (JPLException e) {
    throw new JPLException("Term.toTermArray: term is not a proper list");
   }
   }` i'm calling this function by 'toTermArray(k);` where k is a object which contains the list. Can you please help me with this